# Initialize struct with macro

Tags: c, struct

I have this structure

```
typedef struct {
    int Length;
    int Data[];
} MyStruct;
```

And this macro to initialize the struct

```
#define FillStruct(...)     { .Length = sizeof((int[]){__VA_ARGS__}), .Data = {__VA_ARGS__} }
```

So I can initialize the struct with

```
MyStruct Obj = FillStruct(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

But this doesn´t work. I got this error:

> non-static initialization of a flexible array member

I can compile the code when I change `Obj` into a `static` initialization

```
static MyStruct Obj = FillStruct(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

but now the debugger gives me some weird informations about this object.

[image]

So how can I solve this problem? I´m looking for a solution to intialize this struct during compile time on an embedded device (AVR MCU). In this case I can´t use solutions with `malloc` etc. And the data in this struct is constant and got stored in the program memory. So the application only reads this data.

Comment: The second part (with `static`) seems like just a limitation of your debugger.  The code itself seems fine in this case.

Comment: But the debugger gives me `0xC0AB` as length and the correct length must be `10`. Or does this issue come from the limitation too?

Comment: Have you considered using the NARGS macro hack to make it a fixed size at compile time instead of variable length?

Comment: Certainly when I run your code on my system, Obj.Length is set to 20, as I would expect (`sizeof(int) == 4` for me).  So it seems like this is your debugger (or perhaps your compiler) misbehaving.

Comment: @technosaurus I will test it.

Comment: "In this case I can´t use solutions with malloc" Indeed! You need to get rid of the flexible array member and use a fixed size array instead. Don't use variable length macros either. It's an old AVR, not a PC.

Comment: I´ve updated my question. Thanks @technosaurus for the hint with `NARGS` and shame on me for a little bit of stupidness :). Feel free to tell me your improvements!

Comment: @Kampi: I think it will be better if you would provide the solution as a proper answer, and then you will accept it, and we can vote it. You will even get the "Self-Learner" badge, if you do not have it.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the C standard doesn't support initializing a flexible array member.  The ability to do so, even for `static` objects, is a compiler extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one solution. The compiler throw this error, because I declared and initialize the structure inside of `main`. Moving this segment out of `main` will solve this problem.

The final solution looks like this:

```
#define VA_NARGS_IMPL(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, N, ...) 2 * N
#define VA_NARGS(...) VA_NARGS_IMPL(__VA_ARGS__, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)

#define FillStruct(...)     { .Length = VA_NARGS(__VA_ARGS__), .Data = {__VA_ARGS__} }

const MyStruct Obj = FillStruct(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

int main(void)
{
   int B = Obj.Data[2];
   // B = 3
}
```

So everything is fine now. It seems that the wrong debugger output also appears with `const` keyword. But now I can remove `const` and `static` to get the corrent `Length` (but not `Data`) in the structure.